# GEE 'User memory limit exceeded' - simple reducer works in seconds for fewer features but not full collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

**I'm having a problem with the GEE code 3: 'User memory limit exceeded', which seems a very common user-error related issue especially for new users.** However, on reading the debugging guide and many other similar questions posted on here I still cannot figure out the issue.

**I think my code is simple, yet I must be overlooking something as I have been able to run similar code but using different layers. Any advice on how to streamline my code and potentially avoid this error code would be really appreciated:**

I'm calculating the potential for carbon accumulation from forest regrowth ('carbon' layer) in key areas across the globe ('kba' feature collection). My goal is to have a CSV of the area of carbon accumulation from forest regrowth of all features in the feature collection.

I think my code is very simple, I have used reduceRegions() to identify the sum of carbon within each kba feature, but this does not work on the full feature collection, only a subset. Further I have previously used this feature collection in the same manner to successfully integrate 10+ other layers.

**My question:** Am I overlooking something which is causing an extensive use of GEE memory, or is my issue perhaps related to the 'carbon' layer?

```
  // // // // Carbon accumulation from regrowth // // // 

// Calculate scale
var scale = carbon.projection().nominalScale();

//  // // KBA layer  // // // 

// Calculate area on GEE and convert it into ha
var kba_ha = kba.map(function(f) {
    var Area_ha = f.geometry().area().divide(1e4);
    return f.set({"SitRecID": f.get("SitRecID"),
                     "Area_ha": Area_ha});
});

// Remove unnecessary features 
var kba_globe = kba_ha.filter(ee.Filter.intersects(".geo", ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])).not());


// // //  Calculate carbon accumulation from regrowth for all areas in the feature collection // // //

// // Once have sum of carbon multiply it by the difference between the carbon layers spatial resolution, and hectares 


// The below times out 'Error: User memory limit exceeded. (Error code: 3)' so tried with reduced number of features and works fast

// var density = carbon.reduceRegions({
//     collection: kba_globe,
//     reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
//     scale: scale
//   }) .map (function(f) {
//     var sum_area = ee.Number(f.get("sum")).multiply(100);
//     return f.set({"SitRecID": f.get("SitRecID"),
//                     "Sum": f.get("sum"), 
//                     "Area_ha": f.get("Area_ha"),
//                     "Sum_MgC_ha": sum_area});
// });

// Works well by using 1,000 out of 16,000 features

var kbas = kba_globe.limit(1000);

var density = carbon.reduceRegions({
    collection: kbas,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    scale: scale
  }) .map (function(f) {
    var sum_area = ee.Number(f.get("sum")).multiply(100);
    return f.set({"SitRecID": f.get("SitRecID"),
                    "Sum": f.get("sum"), 
                    "Area_ha": f.get("Area_ha"),
                    "Sum_MgC_ha": sum_area});
});

// Turn resulting feature into feature collection 
var results = ee.FeatureCollection(density);

// function to remove geometry from features 
var remove_geometry = function(feature) {
  return feature.setGeometry(null)};

// map function to remove geomety from features over the whole feature collection
var results_table = results.map(remove_geometry);

// Export the FeatureCollection to Drive as a csv table without geometry
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: results_table,
  description: 'Global_carbon_forest_regrowth_1040',
  folder: 'KBA_pressures',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

**My code:** https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e3361caeb7edb364ff6dfa20113e6f8

Comment: You haven't shared your asset `users/fraserjbell0/young_forest_sequestration_rate_Griscom_extent_April`. It's a very large area you're trying to reduce over, but since the asset isn't shared, it's not clear at which scale. You can try to set `tileScale` to `16` when reducing. You can also try to map over the regions and `reduceRegion()` for every individual region, instead of doing all regions in one go with `reduceRegions()`.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel! I didn't know about the tileScale function, I tried it, and it worked within a couple of minutes. Great suggestion